# Edit pandas DataFrame using indexes

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a general, efficient way to assign values to a subset of a DataFrame in pandas? I've got hundreds of rows and columns that I can access directly but I haven't managed to figure out how to edit their values without iterating through each row,col pair. For example:

```
In [1]: import pandas, numpy

In [2]: array = numpy.arange(30).reshape(3,10)

In [3]: df = pandas.DataFrame(array, index=list("ABC"))

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
A   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
B  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
C  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29

In [5]: rows = ['A','C']

In [6]: columns = [1,4,7]

In [7]: df[columns].ix[rows]
Out[7]: 
    1   4   7
A   1   4   7
C  21  24  27

In [8]: df[columns].ix[rows] = 900

In [9]: df
Out[9]: 
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
A   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
B  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
C  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29
```

I believe what is happening here is that I'm getting a copy rather than a view, meaning I can't assign to the original DataFrame. Is that my problem? What's the most efficient way to edit those rows x columns (preferably in-pace, as the DataFrame may take up a lot of memory)?

Also, what if I want to replace those values with a correctly shaped DataFrame?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#selection-by-label) in an assignment expression (the `=` means it's not relevant whether it is a view or a copy!):

```
In [11]: df.loc[rows, columns] = 99

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
A   0  99   2   3  99   5   6  99   8   9
B  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
C  20  99  22  23  99  25  26  99  28  29
```

*If you're using a version prior to 0.11 you can use `.ix`.*

As [@Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/644898/jeff) comments:

> This is an assignment expression (see ['advanced indexing with ix' section of the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#advanced-indexing-with-ix)) and doesn't return anything (although there are assignment expressions which **do** return things, e.g. `.at` and `.iat`).
>
> `df.loc[rows,columns]` *can* return a view, but usually it's a copy. Confusing, but done for efficiency.
>
> Bottom line: **use** `ix`, `loc`, `iloc` **to set** *(as above)*, and **don't modify copies**.

*See ['view versus copy'](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) section of the docs.*

Comment: I get an attribute error for df.loc. I assume this is new in pandas 0.11. Was there an equivalent before, or is this why I need to upgrade pandas every other month?

Comment: Also, does it describe somewhere in the docs that this is a view, not a copy? See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Comment: Definitely the docs need to extend more about when it's a view or a copy, I've said I would add some docs myself in the past (just need to work out all the ins and outs), will make a github issue to get the ball rolling...

Comment: @Noah Alternative is to use .ix (.loc is less ambiguous). Definitely recommend updating pandas (every other month) to the latest stable version :) 0.12 will be out next week.

Comment: Great, thanks. It'd be great to have this cleared up in the docs, too!

Comment: @Noah created an [issue on github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4183) :)

Comment: Just to expand on @AndyHayden answer. This does not a view *or* a copy, it is an assignment expression, so it doesn't return anything (FYI occasionally there *are* assignement expressions that DO return things, e.g. ``.at/.iat``). However, ``df.loc[rows,columns]`` *can* return a view (more generally its a copy). Confusing, but done for efficiency. Bottom line, is to use ``ix/loc/iloc`` to set, and don't modify copies.

Comment: After a little digging, this appears to use the dictionary-like `__setitem__` functionality in python, which explains why chaining things doesn't work for assignment

Comment: It's not clear to me what "and don't modify copies" means. Anyone care to elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: Copy means underlying data has copied, so if edited it wont affect the original, compared to viee where underlying data is shared. Useful way to think is with examples e.g. python list (exercise: do same in numpy/pandas) A = [1,2,3] ;B=A; C=A[:]; B[0]=7;C[1]=42. What is A?

Comment: _Do the same in numpy_: `A = np.array([1, 2, 3])`, rest the same - `A
array([ 7, 42,  3])` - ouch!