# modifying values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Assuming I've the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'c', 'f', 'a'])
print(df)
```

I can replace any occurrence of 'a' with 'AAA' as follows:

```
df.columns = ['Letters']   
for i, x in enumerate(df['Letters']):
    if x == 'a':
        df['Letters'][i] = "AAA"
print(df)
```

But if I extracted unique row and try to do the same thing, it does not work.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'c', 'f', 'a'])
df.columns = ['Letters']
grouped = df.groupby('Letters')
index = [gp_keys[0] for gp_keys in grouped.groups.values()]
unique_df = df.reindex(index)
print(unique_df) 

for i, x in enumerate(unique_df):
    if x == 'a':
        unique_df.loc[i] = "AAA"
print(unique_df)
```

I am curious why doing `unique_df[i] = "AAA"` no longer modifies the data frame values. Even doing `unique_df.loc[i] = "AAA"` as suggested in the view versus copy post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17557650/edit-pandas-dataframe-using-indexes) seems to make no difference. It seems there is something about the `groupby` function that makes later modification on the data frame elusive. Any thoughts?

Comment: You are using two different things in both cases: `df['Letters']` vs  `unique_df` in the iteration/assignment. So in the second case it tries to set the `i`th column (it is 'Letters', not 'First'). If you replace `unique_df` with `unique_df['Letters']`, it works. But anyway, you should just better do `df.loc[df['Letters']=='a', 'Letters'] = "AAA"` instead of the for loop.

Comment: unique_df.loc[i] = "AAA"  works fine

Comment: @AerofoilKite Are you sure, I am running the following and it's not modifying the value: `for i, x in enumerate(unique_df):
    if x == 'a':
        unique_df.loc[i] = "AAA"
print(unique_df)`

Comment: See my answer, your problem is here: enumerate(unique_df):

Comment: It should be enumerate(unique_df.values):

Comment: @AerofoilKite Changing only enumerate(unique_df) part does not completely resolve it. But your answer may contain what I need. Aside, do you know why `unique_df.loc['Letters'][i] = "AAA"` give the following error: `KeyError: 'the label [Letters] is not in the [index]'`

Comment: It should be `unique_df.loc[i, 'Letters']`, otherwise you are trying to index the rows with 'Letters', which indeed is not working

Comment: @joris I see. Makes sense. Btw, your comment to do the following is right on the money. If you can make it into an answer, would love that. `unique_df.loc[unique_df['Letters']=='a', 'Letters'] = "AAA"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is maybe not fully answering the question, as the example you provided can be simplified, but you really should not enumerate in such a case.
If you want to modify certain values based on a conditions, you can use boolean indexing like:

```
df.loc[df['Letters']=='a', 'Letters'] = "AAA"
```

instead of doing a for loop.

---

The answer the original question: you need to use `unique_df['Letters']` instead of `unique_df` in your second example (as you also did this in the first example).

Comment: Great. Assuming I want to replace more than one value, is there a way of doing it in one swoop instead of stepwise as below: `unique_df.loc[unique_df['Letters']=='a', 'Letters'] = "AAA"
unique_df.loc[unique_df['Letters']=='c', 'Letters'] = "CCC"`

Comment: In such a case, you could also do something like ``unique_df['Letters'].replace(['a', 'c'], ['AAA', 'CCC'])``

Answer (score 0):

You can try it

```
S = unique_df['Letters']

for i, x in enumerate(S):
    if x == 'a':
        unique_df['Letters'][i] = "AAA"
        # unique_df.loc[i] = "AAA"       -- this will work too

print(unique_df)
```

Or, You can use unique_df.values

```
for i, x in enumerate(unique_df.values):
    if x == 'a':
        unique_df['Letters'][i] = "AAA"
        # unique_df.loc[i] = "AAA"      -- this will work too
print(unique_df)
```

Comment: There is no need to convert it to a Series, `unique_df['Letters']` is already a series. Also no need to use `values`, just enumerate `unique_df['Letters']`, or better: don't enumerate at all.